# Is there a way of stopping Outlook from adding unwanted page breaks into emails?

Tags: html, email, outlook, page-break

We generate quite large HTML emails - so hit the Outlook Email Client problem/software flaw where it decides to stick page breaks into the email if it thinks it's reached an A4 number of characters. [This is due to the Outlook Email Client using the Word engine to render it's HTML.]

This would not be a problem to us except that

1. It may occur in the middle of some HTML.
2. It's destructive.

Example of 1: If you have some html

```
<img src="http://
```

you may get
`><img` **PAGE BREAK HERE**

`src="http://`

Example of 2: If you have some html

```
<img src="http://
```

you may get
`>**PAGE BREAK HERE** img src="http://`

Which has destroyed the "<" of the "`<img`" tag.

Our emails are dynamic so each one may have this page break issue at different points in each email. :o( We try to get around it with 'sacrificial' areas of blank spaces to absord the page breaks - but this system starts to break down as our emails are become more complex over time.

Example of a potential work-around that did not work for us:
[Mike The Coder - Page Break Before Always](http://mikethecoder.com/post/861597102/outlook-2007-screws-up-spacing-where-page-breaks-would)
Post that mentions issues in this area:
[Horizontal Spacing Issues in Outlook 2007 and 2010](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010)

Do people know of other ways of trying to stop this or of working around it in the Outlook email client?

Answer (score 1):

This article discusses a possible fix, but it would require a registry edit:

http://www.msofficeforums.com/outlook/6277-prevent-outlook-adding-line-breaks.html

Here is another article that has a workaround that could work for you possibly, without having to edit the registry:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/line-break-in-plain-text-emails-in-outlook-2010/11d69847-f576-4002-b2fb-67bc59a69ce6?tab=AllReplies&tm=1329162544193